# Javascript to swap image

Tags: javascript

I have a full image and a bunch of thumbnail images.  I want to replace the full image with the image link of whatever thumbnail was clicked.  Here is the code:  Thanks

```
function swapImage() {
    var fullCoverImage = document.getElementById("full_cover");

    var linkedImage = this.childNodes[0];
    var thumbSource = linkedImage.getAttribute("src");

    var coverSource = fullCoverImage.getAttribute("src");

    var newSource = thumbSource.replace("_thumb","");
    fullCoverImage.setAttribute("src", newSource);  
}

<a id="slide_thumb" onClick="swapImage();" href="Javascript:void(0);"><img src="images/portfolio/fiction_001_thumb.png" /></a>
<a id="slide_thumb" onClick="swapImage();" href="Javascript:void(0);"><img src="images/portfolio/fiction_002_thumb.png" /></a>

<img id="full_cover" src="images/portfolio/fiction_001.png" />
```

Comment: `this` does not refer to the `<a>` that called `swapImage`

Comment: "It doesn't work" is _never_ a sufficient problem description. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
function swapImage(aTag) {
    var fullCoverImage = document.getElementById("full_cover");

    var linkedImage = aTag.childNodes[0];
    var thumbSource = linkedImage.getAttribute("src");

    var coverSource = fullCoverImage.getAttribute("src");

    var newSource = thumbSource.replace("_thumb","");
    fullCoverImage.setAttribute("src", newSource);  
}

<a id="slide_thumb" onClick="swapImage(this);" href="Javascript:void(0);"><img src="images/portfolio/fiction_001_thumb.png" /></a>
<a id="slide_thumb" onClick="swapImage(this);" href="Javascript:void(0);"><img src="images/portfolio/fiction_002_thumb.png" /></a>

<img id="full_cover" src="images/portfolio/fiction_001.png" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `onClick="swapImage();"` to `onClick="swapImage(this);"`
and use

> ```
> function swapImage(ele) {
>     var fullCoverImage = document.getElementById("full_cover");
>
>     var linkedImage = ele.childNodes[0];
>     var thumbSource = linkedImage.getAttribute("src");
>
>     var coverSource = fullCoverImage.getAttribute("src");
>
>     var newSource = thumbSource.replace("_thumb","");
>     fullCoverImage.setAttribute("src", newSource);  
> }
> ```

Edit: beaten to it.